# Normal states on a type III$_1$ factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a type III$_1$ factor. Suppose $\rho$ is a normal state on $M$, given any $c\in [0,2]$, can we find a normal state $\rho'$ on $M$ such that $\|\rho-\rho'\|=c$? Or can we find a sequence of normal states $\rho_n$ such that $\|\rho-\rho_n\|\to c$ as $n\to \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get $c = 2$, but you can do this for any $c \in [0,2)$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, find a projection $p \in M$ with $\rho(p) < \epsilon$ and then find $\rho'$ supported on $p$. Then $$(\rho - \rho')(1 - 2p) = 1 - 2\rho(p) - 1 + 2 = 2(1 - \rho(p)),$$ showing that $\|\rho - \rho'\|$ can be arbitrarily close to $2$. Then linearly interpolating between $\rho$ and $\rho'$ gives you normal states of any intermediate distance to $\rho$.

Comment: I have a question : If we take $c=1$, how to use $\rho$ and $\rho'$ to construct another normal state $\rho''$ such that $\|\rho-\rho''\|=1$?

Comment: If we take $p=1-s(\rho)$, then$\rho(p)=0$  and hence $\|\rho-\rho'\|=2$.

Comment: The distance from $t\rho' + (1 - t)\rho$ to $\rho$, for $0 < t < 1$, is $t\cdot \|\rho' - \rho\|$. If you want $c = 1$, find $\rho'$ such that this distance is greater than $1$ and take $t = \frac{1}{\|\rho' - \rho\|}$.

Comment: As to your second comment, that only works if $s(\rho) \neq 1$.

Comment: I don't understand why we check that $\|\rho–\rho'\|$ can be arbitrarily close to 2.

Comment: Because, as shown in the displayed line, this difference takes values as close to 2 as you like on a norm one element, $1 - 2p$.

Comment: Or do you mean why is it important to check this? I don't understand the question.